# How do I reorient my cylinder with a unit vector?

Tags: openscad

I know the unit vector of the axis to a cylinder oriented in 3D space. Is there any module or function in OpenSCAD to reorient the cylinder after I create it about the z-axis? Regular rotate function just rotates about the corresponding axis but I have the angle between the central axis to the cylinder and my coordinate axis.

Comment: Can you give an example of your vector and what you expect as the result?

Answer (score 0):

Look at the line module in the User Manual:

https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenSCAD_User_Manual/Tips_and_Tricks#Drawing_%22lines%22_in_OpenSCAD